# How to change log4j2 logging path on tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, log4j, spring-boot, log4j2

I'm running a webapp on `tomcat` using `spring-boot`.

How could I change the `log4j2.xml` logging path dynamically? (eg by jvm args, property file, or else)?

So far I configured the log xml as follows:

```
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <property name="path">${bundle:application:log.path}</property>
    </Properties>
</Configuration>
```

With configuration file:

```
#application.properties:
log.path=d:/
```

Now I want to dynamically force the logpath to eg `d:/log-test`, but without having to modify my `war` file. Because on redeployment I would lose any manual configuration.

So how could I provide a different logging path?

I want to run multiple profiles on the same machine, so environment or system properties are of no use for me here.

Comment: The war file on deployment should get un-jar'd and you should be then able to modify your properties file directly. You would just have to restart the application so that log4j reads the properties file again.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal that's exactly what I want to prevent, as when deploying a new version I'd have to explicit modify the war file each time. not saying a collegue might miss that important step...

Comment: Log path is seldom absolute and it's not like one changes it at every deployment. The final path would obviously be committed to your repository and reflect in the final build. What's the use of externalizing values to a properties file if you still feel the need to override it? Doing it post-build, kind of defeats its purpose I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it in multiple ways mentioned [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

if you want by environment variable then you could do something like:

```
${env:MY_LOG_PATH}
```

if System properties then:

```
${sys:MY_LOG_PATH}
```

Comment: Neither of these is property useful for me as I want to run test + dev profile on the same machine.

Comment: So you should clearly mention that. You just said "Now I want to dynamically force the logpath to eg d:/log-test, but without having to modify my war file." Why it wont work for you? Cant you define two different system property on same machine?

Comment: If I define 2 different system props, I then have to explicit edit the logfile content of my war. again this is what I want prevent.

Comment: isn't that system property property driven? dev you have one, UAT you have one and prod you have one? If that's not the case then am afraid anything will help.

Comment: Probably you're right and running the webapp in different tomcats with each having a env variable set is probably the right solution.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been suggested using ${sys:LOG_PATH} is probably the best solution. You do not have to modify the war, but you do have to run a tomcat for dev and a separate tomcat for test. Then just place set CATALINA_OPTS to include -DLOG_PATH=/my/log/path in setenv.sh or setenv.bat It really wouldn't make a lot of sense to have a single tomcat running both anyway.